# Base class pointer pointing to derived class, outside of a scope

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, derived-class, base-class

If I create a base class pointer array, create an derived class object in a scope and pass the reference to the array and call a virtual function of the derived class in the scope correctly but outside that scope, I try calling the virtual function, it forgets it was a derived class. I tried casting it but it doesn't work.

```
class Base{
    public:
        Base(string str) {name = str;}
        virtual string toString() { return name;}
        Base& operator=(const Base& b) {name = b.name; return *this;}
    private:
        string name;
};
class Derived: public Base{
    public:
        Derived(string str1, string str2) {name = str1; second = str2;}
        virtual string toString() {return name + second;}
        Derived& operator=(const Derived& d) {Base::operator=(d);
                                              second = d.second; return *this;}
    private:
        string name;
        string second;
};
int main(){
    Base* baseArr[5];
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    if(n==1){
        Derived der("Derived", "Class");
        baseArr[0] = &der;
        baseArr[0]->toString() << endl; //this prints out "DerivedClass"
     }
     cout << baseArr[0]->toString(); //this prints out "Derived"
 }
```

Is there any way to call the derived class' function outside the scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're invoking *undefined behaviour*, because you are referring to an object instance through `baseArr[0]` that has already been destructed. The lifetime of `der` does not exist past the `}` at the end of its scope, and you cannot refer to it through the pointer you stored after that point.

Comment: So, is there any way to preserve der past the }?

Comment: Sure, move its declaration outside the `if (...) {` scope, then its lifetime will extend to the final `}` in `main()`.

Comment: But, I need that if statement for my actual code. Because I'm trying to create 2 different derived classes. Like Derived1 if the condition is true, or Derived2 if false and both of them inherit from Base.

Comment: Okay, you can allocate one using `new` instead of a local variable. `Derived *der = new Derived("Derived", "Class");` and then `baseArray[0] = der;`. Don't forget to delete it when you are done with it.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! About the deleting, is it okay to just delete the array at the end of main or each Derived classes (assuming I made destructors for them)?

Comment: Deleting the array does not delete instances pointed to by pointers in the array. You will need to either: (1) delete the instances yourself, or (2) use an appropriate smart pointer class to take care of that for you.

Comment: So, I can do a for loop and delete each instance at the end of main, right? I read up on smart pointers and it looks a little daunting.

Comment: A for loop will work just fine (however, don't forget to initialise each of the pointers in your array to NULL because that's not done for you). You don't have to use smart pointers right away, and maybe it's best not to so you can have a better appreciation for what they do for you when you do start to use them!